# Webpack babel-loader output size

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs, webpack-2, babel-loader

I have a lazy chunkhash output from my application and on closer inspection i cant work out why the login.vue file seems to appear twice. Once as itself and once within babel-loader. Im using webpack-visualizer to view this.

The total size of the file is 3.2kb but i want to make sure im not doubling up on anything here.

[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3]
Thanks all.

Comment: Why not simply check your built file's JavaScript source and see if any of the unique content from your component is being duplicated. You can spot it instantly that way instead of trying to take a guess with a bundle visualizer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to to be in the bundle twice no but i want to try and understand why it would be represented twice like this within a visualizer.